# Subtotal for rdlc Report

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I try to write an order with the subtotal at the end of each page and the total sum with VAT at the end of the last page.

But all I get until now is either the subtotal after each order position or the total sum at the end.

I use a tablix filled with data from DataSetOrder.
Then I create a group in the table for each order position. I have also added a foot for the group with the statement "=RunningValue(Fields!Gesamtpreis.Value, Sum, Nothing)". 
But this is how I get the subtotal after each position.

So what do I have to do to get the subtotal only once for each page an the total sum at the end of the last page?

```
 public static List<Invoice> GetInvoicePositions(string sInvoiceNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            using (entities1 ctx = new entities1())
            {
                var query = (from d in ctx.tbldelivery
                             join dp in ctx.tbldeliverypos on d.DeliveryID equals dp.DeliveryID
                             join op in ctx.tblorderpos on dp.OrderPositionID equals op.OrderPositionID
                             join o in ctx.tblorder on op.OrderID equals o.OrderID
                             join p in ctx.tblpart on op.partnumber equals p.partnumber
                             where dp.Invoicenumber == sInvoiceNumber
                             select new Invoice
                             {
                                 OrderPositionID = (Int16)op.OrderPositionID,
                                 DeliveryNoteNumber = d.DeliveryNoteNumber,
                                 DeliveryDate = (DateTime)d.DeliveryDate,
                                 DeliveryAmount = (Int16)dp.DeliveryAmount,
                                 Partnumber = op.partnumber,
                                 OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber,
                                 SinglePrice = (double)op.SinglePrice,
                                 CustomerNumber = o.CustomerNumber,
                                 DeliveryId = d.DeliveryID
                             }).ToList();

                return query;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ex.InnerException.Message, "Datenbankfehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Can we see more of a code example.

Comment: What code or screenshot would be helpful? DB-Query? Or the report design?

Comment: Post the methods involved, so we can get a better grasp on whats going on with your code.